# How to autowire in non Spring objects without using the ApplicationContext to get Beans by name

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I am currently working on a Spring Boot project and have some trouble with autowiring.
First, here is the functionality of the program: 
There is an external program where users can type commands. These commands trigger an event in a library I use (a library that wraps an API) which my code needs to handle. This event contains the raw command text like "help" and I match that to a list of available commands. If a matching command is found it gets executed (with all the event data as it might include specific informations).
I have a Command Interface and a base implementation of that Interface. Every command that the program can handle is a subclass of that base implementation. Before I used Spring I just matched the text to a command in a factory and returned the fitting command as a new object
(like `return new Help();`). Due to all commands being a subclass of the implementation of that interface they all have a method to execute the command. Every request to the database happened in another class with static methods that got called from within the different command execution methods. 
Now with Spring I have the opportunity to use Repositories that handle all the database communication so I do not need to rely on such a class. However, for the commands to be able to use an autowired repository they need to be controlled by Spring. Currently I use the `ApplicationContext` to receive a bean by its name and define all commands as `@Bean` in a `@Configuration` class. (There are multiple repositories even though the example command only uses one!)

The command interface:

```java
public interface Command {

    /*  Executes the command and forwards the event received by the library
     *  to the execution method which uses its information.
     */
    void execute(SomeEvent event);

    // other methods...
}
```

The basic command implementation:

```java
@Service
public class CommandImpl implements Command {

    // Can be used for unknown commands, does not do anything.
    @Override
    public void execute(SomeEvent event) {
        // subclasses contain the information, this one does not do anything
    }

    // other interface method implementations...
}
```

A simple command implementation:

```java
public class Help extends CommandImpl {

    // SomeRepository refers to an Interface which extends a Spring JPA Repository like CrudRepository
    private final SomeRepository repo;

    @Autowired
    public Help(SomeRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(SomeEvent event) {
        /* gets data from the SomeEvent object (like caller) and uses 
         * SomeRepository to receive database settings and permissions.
         * Displays help for the specific caller (only commands he/she can use 
         * based on the permissions received from the repository)
         */
    }
}
```

The Spring `ApplicationContext` wrapper:

```java
@Component
public class SpringContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringContext.class);

    /*
     * Get a Spring-controlled object of a command implementation by name.
     */
    public static Command getCommandBean(String name) {
        Command command;
        try {
            command = context.getBean(name, Command.class);
        } catch (NoSuchBeanDefinitionException e) {
            LOGGER.error("The command \"" + name + "\" does not exist or is not defined as a Bean!");

            // returning the base implementation as that will do nothing on execution.
            command =  new CommandImpl();
        }

        return command;
    }

    /*
     * Spring controlled method which provides the ApplicationContext on startup.
     */
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(@NotNull ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
        SpringContext.context = context;
    }
}
```

The Bean Configuration for the different commands:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    Help help(SomeRepository repo) {
        return new Help(repo);
    }

    // other commands defined as @Bean...
}
```

The listener that gets triggered by the library event and executes a fitting command:

```
@Service
public class CommandListener extends SomeLibraryListenerAdapter {

    
    @Override
    public void onSomeEvent(@NotNull final SomeEvent event) {
        // perform some checks if event contains a command and if caller is authorized to use it...
        // execute command
        final String commandName = identifyCommand(...); // commandName is a guaranteed match to some command when it arrives here
        final Command command = SpringContext.getCommandBean(commandName);
        command.execute(event);
    }
}
```

I've read that it is desirable to not use the `ApplicationContext` as it works against the Dependency Injection principle of Spring but I do not quite understand how I can avoid using it. Furthermore, it seems to me that as I do have control over all these commands there has to be a way where I can use Spring in a way so that I do not need to use the `ApplicationContext` to get a fitting bean with the required autowiring. \

I tried to mark the command classes as `@Service` and use `@Autowired` on its fields as I cant use the Constructor because then the factory would need to know which command needs which repositories. Another issue is that I can not use `new` anymore and thus the factory idea does not work. 
I also read about a `BeanFactory` but I do not really grasp the concept behind it. The texts I read about it defined the values for the entities in a XML file which I don't think would work for me as I do not work with value objects but with command implementations. 
Last thing I saw is the `@Configurable` annotation which could be used but that would require AspectJ and some sort of weaving which seems to be overkill for such a basic functionality. However, if there is no other way I would probably continue to use the ApplicationContext instead of using that solution.

So in summary my question is how I can restructure my code to use autowiring on my commands without using the `ApplicationContext` and instead work with really simple and clean Spring annotations; or some tips in the right direction like what pattern/functionality to use here.
If there is no way then a I would be glad about a short explanation on why it does not work.

Kind Regards 
Galaxaisio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering `Help` and other subclasses of CommandImpl are configured as Spring beans , the following code will serve the purpose.

```
@Service
public class CommandListener extends SomeLibraryListenerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    Map<String,Command> commandMap;    

    @Override
    public void onSomeEvent(@NotNull final SomeEvent event) {
        // perform some checks if event contains a command and if caller is authorized to use it...
        // execute command
        final String commandName = identifyCommand(...); // commandName is a guaranteed match to some command when it arrives here
        final Command command = commandMap.get(commandName);
        command.execute(event);
    }
}
```

Here the key for the Map would be the bean name.

Reference : https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#beans-autowired-annotation ( Section starting with "Even typed Map instances can be autowired " )